# Gatsby-browser.ts wont enable theming

Tags: typescript, gatsby, styled-components

I created a theming functionality using Gatsby, styled-components and typescript and I tried to implement it but no change occurred.

The code of the Gatsby-browser.tsx was as follows:

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider, createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';
import type { GatsbyBrowser } from 'gatsby';

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle<{ theme: { main: string } }>`
    body {
        background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.main};
    }
`;

interface GlobalStyleProps {
  theme: {
    main: string;
  };
}

const defaultProps = {
  theme: {
    main: '#fff',
  },
};

const StyledGlobalStyle = (props: GlobalStyleProps) => (
  <GlobalStyle theme={props.theme} />
);

StyledGlobalStyle.defaultProps = defaultProps;

const theme = {
  main: 'mediumseagreen',
};

export const wrapPageElement: GatsbyBrowser['wrapPageElement'] = ({ element }) => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <StyledGlobalStyle />
      {element}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```